# Como obtener el valor máximo de un campo dependiendo de la fecha y que me permita obtener el campo de registrado_por?

Tags: postgresql, sql

Necesito obtener el valor máximo por cada fecha de cada registro realizado ,hasta el momento estoy realizando esta consulta.

```
select re,fe,max(contador) turno 
FROM(select registrado_por as re, to_char (creadoel-'9 
hours'::interval,'yyyy-mm-dd') as fe,count(1) contador 
from registro group by re,fe )t 
group by  re,fe order by 2 desc
```

[image: este resultado me genera hasta ahora]

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794)

Answer (score 0):

Logre obtener los datos con el que tenia turno máximo según la fecha.
con la siguiente consulta , me faltaba unir las tablas con INNER JOIN .

```
select t1.re,t2.fe,t2.contador from
```

(select registrado_por as re, to_char (creadoel-'9 hours'::interval,'yyyy-mm-dd') as fe,count(1) contador from registro group by re,fe) t1 
JOIN 
(select fe,max(contador) contador FROM (select registrado_por as re, to_char (creadoel-'9 hours'::interval,'yyyy-mm-dd') as fe,count(1) as contador from registro group by re,fe )t group by  1 order by 1 desc) t2 
ON (t1.fe=t2.fe and t1.contador=t2.contador) order by 2 desc

[image]